# What is the latest issue featuring the Earth-616 Spider-Man?

Tags: marvel, comics, spider-man

What is the latest comic released about Spider-Man from Earth-616? I can't find any info about that and wonder what is happening in Peter Parker's life?

Comment: You might consider rephrasing the question to be more specific (eg "As of 2023, what is the latest comic about Earth-616 Spider-Man?"). Otherwise, it's unlikely there will ever be a definitive answer as time goes on.

Comment: @MiloP Mean right now!

Comment: Yes, but questions on Stack Exchange are meant to be useful for future users as well. If we want the question to be useful for a user in 2025, you'd need to either explain its scope or accept a new answer every time there's a new issue of the comic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're definitely looking for *The Amazing Spider-Man*.

The [current volume](https://www.marvel.com/comics/series/32866/the_amazing_spider-man_2022_-_present) started last year, and is presently on issue [#18](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/102186/the_amazing_spider-man_2022_18).